Proving adjacency reduces arrangements in a square matrix
The number of arrangements of $k$ elements on a square matrix of size $n\times n$ can be calculated as $\binom{n^2}{k}$.
However, I am trying to calculate the arrangements of $k$ elements in the same matrix when 2 of them are adjacent with Moore neighborhood, meaning they can be adjacent on diagonal entries too.
As I don´t need an exact number for such quantity, my question is: Is there any way to prove that the arrangements of $k$ elements when 2 of them are adjacent is less than the original amount $\binom{n^2}{k}$?
Formally, we can denote the arrangements when 2 elements are adjacent as $f(n^2,k)$ and state:
$$f(n^2,k)<\binom{n^2}{k}$$
Also, if this may not hold for any $n,k$ values, I would suffice to prove that the asymptotic growth of $f(n^2,k)$ is smaller when the matrix size tends to infinity:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n^2,k)}{\binom{n^2}{k}}=0$$

The strict inequality $f(n^2,k) < \binom{n^2}{k}$ holds as soon as there is at least one arrangement that is ruled out: it holds for all $k \le \lceil n/2\rceil^2$. The statement about the limiting behavior asks for something much stronger than $<$, though as stated it only addresses the case where $k$ is held constant as $n \to \infty$.

We can think of $f(n^2,k)/\binom{n^2}{k}$ as the probability that, if $k$ entries are chosen uniformly at random, then $2$ of them are adjacent. The advantage of this interpretation is that we can use classic tools of probability (though in this case they could be reinterpreted as some arguments about summations, too).
Let's first consider the $k=2$ case. What can we say about $f(n^2,2)/\binom{n^2}{2}$: the probability that two random positions in the grid are adjacent? Well, if we choose one of the positions first, there are $n^2-1$ ways to choose the other; of them, at most $8$ are adjacent to the first. So we have $f(n^2,2)/\binom{n^2}{2} \le \frac{8}{n^2-1}$.
For general $k$, we have $\binom k2$ pairs of entries to consider. Each pair has at most a $\frac{8}{n^2-1}$ chance of being adjacent. By the union bound, the total probability that we get any adjacent pair satisfies $$\frac{f(n^2,k)}{\binom{n^2}{k}} \le \binom k2 \frac{8}{n^2-1} = \frac{4k(k-1)}{n^2-1}.$$
We can see that this upper bound goes to $0$ for all constant $k$, and even in some cases where $k \to \infty$ with $n$, provided that $k \ll n$. By the squeeze theorem, the same is true about the limit we're interested in.

Thanks for the answer. Also, could this be generalized for more than 2 adjacent elements? Perhaps with a bound similar to $\frac{a}{n^2-k_0+1}$ where $a$ is the maximum amount of neighbors a cluster of $k_0$ elements can have?
